# Deserialising XML with name and type as attributes

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I'm attempting to use use [Serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde) and [quick-xml](https://crates.io/crates/quick-xml) to deserialise an XML document. However, the type of the element and the name of the item in the parent struct are both in XML attributes:

```
<Root>
    <Attribute Name="MAKE" Type="String">Ford</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="INSURANCE_GROUP" Type="Integer">10</Attribute>
</Root>
```

I would like to deserialise that into this struct:

```rust
struct Root {
    make: String,
    insurance_group: u8,
}
```

I've tried using the tag attribute on the parent to specify that it should use "Type" as the object type, but I have no idea how to tell it to use "Name" as the variable name in the struct. Everything I've tried results in `Err value: Custom("missing field MAKE")'`.

This code should demonstrate the issue:

```rust
use quick_xml::de::from_str;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "Type", rename_all = "SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE")] // What else do I add here to specify "Name"?
struct Root {
    make: String,
    insurance_group: u8,
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let xml = r#"<Root>
        <Attribute Name="MAKE" Type="String">Ford</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="INSURANCE_GROUP" Type="Integer">10</Attribute>
    </Root>"#;
    let import: Root = from_str(xml).unwrap();
    dbg!(&import);
}
```

Ideally I would like to access the values directly using `import.make` (without needing to `match` an `enum`), but I realise this may not be feasible.

Comment: Side question: Do you need the information in `Type`? It seems that the type would be decided once the `Name` is known?

Comment: @Caesar good point, no, I don't. The type is directly associated with the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way of convincing `quick_xml` to use an attribute as the key for a field. You can deserialize into:

```rust
use serde_with::{serde_as, DisplayFromStr};

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "Name", rename_all = "SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE")]
enum Attribute {
    Make {
        #[serde(rename = "$value")]
        make: String,
    },
    InsuranceGroup {
        #[serde(rename = "$value")]
        #[serde_as(as = "DisplayFromStr")]
        insurance_group: u8,
    },
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename = "Root")]
struct SerdeRoot {
    #[serde(rename = "Attribute")]
    attributes: Vec<Attribute>,
}
```

Now, if you insist on using your original data structure, you can additionally do something like

```rust
use derive_builder::Builder;

#[derive(Serialize, Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Builder)]
#[serde(try_from = "SerdeRoot", into = "SerdeRoot")]
struct Root {
    make: String,
    insurance_group: u8,
}

impl TryFrom<SerdeRoot> for Root {
    type Error = RootBuilderError;
    fn try_from(value: SerdeRoot) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let mut builder = RootBuilder::default();
        for a in value.attributes {
            match a {
                Attribute::Make { make } => builder.make(make),
                Attribute::InsuranceGroup { insurance_group } => {
                    builder.insurance_group(insurance_group)
                }
            };
        }
        builder.build()
    }
}
```

which will ultimately make your `from_str::<Root>(xml)` work as desired. (You'd also need an `Into<SerdeRoot>` implementation and some extra fields for `Type` if you want to make serialization work, but that should be easy.)

Comment: That's great, thanks! I didn't expect it to be so complex but I can probably simplify it with macros.