# Using macro output as a method name

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a macro that automatically expands a set of enum variants into a builder (base on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400429/deserialising-xml-with-name-and-type-as-attributes), though I don't think that's relevant). Basically, I want to pass it a value, a builder struct and a list of enum variants and generate match arms. The result should be equivalent to this:

```rust
match a {
    Attribute::InsuranceGroup { value } => builder.insurance_group(value),
};
```

I think I've managed to get fairly close, but I can't figure out how to convert the UpperCamelCase `InsuranceGroup` to lower_camel_case `insurance_group` using the [casey](https://docs.rs/casey/latest/casey/) crate, in order to call the builder method. Currently, I have:

```rust
macro_rules! unwrap_value {
    ($var:ident, $builder:ident, [ $( $enum:ident :: $variant:ident ),+ $(,)? ]) => {
        match $var {
            $($enum::$variant { value } => $builder.snake!($variant) (value),)*
        }
    }
}

unwrap_value! {
    a, builder, [Attribute::InsuranceGroup]
}
```

However, this fails at `$builder.snake!($variant)` with the analyser complaining that it expects `(`, `,`, `.`, `::`, `?`, `}` or an operator, instead of `!`.

I also tried moving `snake!` outside, `snake!($builder.$variant)`, but then it says it can't find `$builder` in this scope.

While I would be interested in any suggestions of alternatives to using the builder which would eliminate this problem, I'm more interested in understanding what I'm doing wrong with the macros in order to better understand them.

Comment: I've added an answer using the paste crate. If anyone can explain how I can "escape" the `snake!` macro I was using originally, I would still like to understand that.

Comment: I don't think you can. Macros are fairly limited in the contexts they can appear in.

Comment: Really off-topic, but I would probably do `$enum:ident :: { $($variant:ident),* } $(,)?` to pass the enum name only once (replaced `[]` by `{}` to match `use` declarations).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks for the suggestion! Yes, I noticed that later and changed it to only pass the enum name once. Though matching the style of `use` is definitely a good idea, I just left the square brackets. I'll change that.

Comment: @David When writing macros, I (and not only I) tends to match the Rust syntax in order to be familiar even if this adds overhead. In this case it doesn't even do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would strongly recomment using the `paste` crate (23,999,580 total downloads vs 7,611 for `casey` as the time of writing, `paste` is even available on the playground!), I will explain here why `casey` didn't work for the sake of knowledge (and suggest a solution! But one you shouldn't use).

---

The first version didn't work because macros cannot be used after the dot. [You can check that out easily](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8dbeb01bf6189b8a01a08bc5d4062222):

```rust
macro_rules! m {
    () => { m };
}
v.m!();
```

```
error: expected one of `(`, `.`, `::`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator, found `!`
 --> src/main.rs:6:4
  |
6 | v.m!();
  |    ^ expected one of 7 possible tokens
```

Neither they will be allowed here in the future (probably), because this will collide (and confuse) with the possibility for [postfix macros](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2442) in the future. This is stated by the reference, too: no [*MacroInvocation*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/macros.html#macro-invocation) is allowed after the dot in [*MethodCallExpr*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html), [*TupleIndexingExpr*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/tuple-expr.html#tuple-indexing-expressions) or [*FieldExpr*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/field-expr.html).

The natural solution is to wrap the whole call in macros (insert the `(value)` also there, because otherwise it considers that as if you've written `(v.method)(value)` and that is invalid method call): `snake!($builder.$variant(value))`.

However, now the compiler complains with a strange error:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `builder` in this scope
  --> src\lib.rs:6:44
   |
6  |               $($enum::$variant { value } => snake!($builder.$variant(value)),)*
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a unit struct with a similar name exists: `Builder`
...
17 |   struct Builder;
   |   --------------- similarly named unit struct `Builder` defined here
...
26 | /     unwrap_value! {
27 | |         a, builder, [Attribute::InsuranceGroup]
28 | |     }
   | |_____- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `snake` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

What? WHAT?? Surely `builder` is in scope! We declared it! Just straight before the macro call (me at least)!

The result is [macro hygiene](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#hygiene).

How does `snake!()` generates its identifiers? Well, [let's dive into the code](https://docs.rs/casey/0.3.3/src/casey/lib.rs.html#15)...

```rust
Ident::new(&transform(ident.to_string()), Span::call_site())
```

Hmm, let's go to [the docs of `Span::call_site()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.call_site)...

> The span of the invocation of the current procedural macro. **Identifiers created with this span will be resolved as if they were written directly at the macro call location** (call-site hygiene) and other code at the macro call site will be able to refer to them as well.

(Emphasis mine. "The macro" here refers to the calling proc-macro, i.e. `snake!()` in this case).

And indeed, we can reproduce this error if we just spell out `builder` ourselves. Because **the macro doesn't see `builder`. It can only see variables it created**. In fact, using call-site hygiene here is a bug of `casey`. `paste` does the correct thing and uses the hygiene of the original identifier.

In fact, this just reveals a bigger problem with our approach: what if the variable will not be snake-cased already? It should be, but if not, we will snake-case it incorrectly!

But what can we do? The `paste` crate gives us proper control over what identifiers we want to change, but `casey` does not (another reason to choose `paste`)! Can we walk against our proc macro?

Can we??

Maybe. I see at least one approach that doesn't require us to do that (find it yourself!). But I actually *do* want to work against our proc-macro. Try at least. Because why not? It's funny.

[`snake!()` doesn't look into groups](https://docs.rs/casey/0.3.3/src/casey/lib.rs.html#37). That means, it will change something like `AbC` - but not something like `(AbC)`. So we can just wrap `$builder` in parentheses...

```rust
$($enum::$variant { value } => snake!(($builder).$variant(value)),)*
```

(No need to handle `value` because it is already snake-cased, and originates in our macro).

And it works! Voilà! (**You should not depend on that. This may be a bug and subject to changes.**)

Comment: I accepted your answer since it actually explains the problem, which I couldn't. Great explanation! Call site hygiene is complicated, I'll have to look into that. Regarding the issue at the end, I was aware of that but knew it wouldn't be a problem in my case. Interesting workaround though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well after hunting for hours I finally found a solution shortly after posting. Instead of using the casey crate I'm using the [paste](https://docs.rs/paste/latest/paste/) crate, which includes the functionality I need. The macro code then becomes:

```rust
macro_rules! unwrap_value {
    ($var:ident, $builder:ident, [ $( $enum:ident :: $variant:ident ),+ $(,)? ]) => {
        match $var {
            $($enum::$variant { value } => paste!($builder.[<$variant:snake>](value)) ,)*
        }
    }
}
```